# IIS stopped responding, w3wp.exe cannot be killed

Tags: iis, w3wp

IIS suddenly stopped working.
When I try to open "Sites" in IIS Manager, it stops respond to my actions.
After iisreset it creates new w3wp.exe processes, that cannot be killed and in the Task Manager there is an empty field "Command Line" in all of these processes, while the "healthy" w3wp always shows the command line parameters.

Any ideas what can cause the problem?

Answer (score -2):

To stop w3wp.exe permanently uninstall 'Microsoft Web Server' from your system. Uninstalling applications can leave invalid registry entries, accumulating over time.

You can find more information here: http://www.processlibrary.com/en/directory/files/w3wp/25761/

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting.. Can one of the downvoters explain please??